# Beacon being detected with null properties

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, kontakt.io

I am using the React Native Kontakt.io wrapper [example](https://github.com/Driversnote-Dev/react-native-kontaktio/blob/master/Example/src/Example.android.js) to test my Kontakt.io beacons. They are being detected by the app, however, most of the properties, such as uniqueId and name, are returned by the beacon as null (as well as the battery level and firmware version being returned as "-1"). Any ideas how to fix this?